# How to make google-mlkit text recognition work in a flutter app

Tags: flutter, google-mlkit, text-recognition

I'm trying to make a flutter app that uses google-mlkit text recognition to extract the text of receipts. I got it working but there are still isues. Some single letters don't get recognized and sometimes even full words or numbers dont get picked up.

I implemented my app following this guide https://blog.codemagic.io/text-recognition-using-firebase-ml-kit-flutter/.

In this picture you can see what i mean that some numbers and text dont get picked up. [1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nR5SP.jpg

Does anyone know what the problem could be? Any suggestions? Thanks in advance for the help and I will list some ways i have tried to fix it.

-Changed the cameracontroller picture resolution from high to max and ultra.
-Changed my dependecy to the newest version.
-Changed to mlkit text recognition v2
-Tried using the google_ml_vision https://pub.dev/packages/google_ml_vision

(Its also not the case that these missing words/numbers dont get marked with a rectangle.)

Comment: The google_ml_vision flutter plugging is neither owned, nor endorsed by Google. You can post your question using its support page: https://github.com/brianmtully/flutter_google_ml_vision/issues

Answer (score 0):

You can use google_ml_kit package. It works with Google's standalone ML Kit. So no need to register project on firebase. It is a recommended package for standalone ml kit as firebase_ml_vission package is discontinued.

Recently google_ml_kit package is split into a set of packages. For text recognition, [google_mlkit_text_recognition](https://pub.dev/packages/google_mlkit_text_recognition) package is created.

For text recognition, you can use below code,

```
final textRecognizer = TextRecognizer();
final RecognizedText recognizedText = await textRecognizer.processImage(inputImage);

String text = recognizedText.text;
for (TextBlock block in recognizedText.blocks) {
  final Rect rect = block.rect;
  final List<Offset> cornerPoints = block.cornerPoints;
  final String text = block.text;
  final List<String> languages = block.recognizedLanguages;

  for (TextLine line in block.lines) {
    // Same getters as TextBlock
    for (TextElement element in line.elements) {
      // Same getters as TextBlock
    }
  }
}
```

To know, how to add text recognition using google_ml_kit, you can refer this [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jZqTjFOxiC4).